# problem sqlalchemy full text search by ts_rank

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I need to make the ts_rank just in the order by ()

```
query = sqlalchemy.sql.select([table],table).where(sqlalchemy.sql.expression.func.to_tsvector('english', table.c.title )\.match(' machine & Verificated',postgresql_regconfig='english')).order_by( )#
```

Thanks

Comment: I don't even know how to edit that. Just paste your code in a single block, highlight it all and use CTRL + k

Comment: it is a very long code so i just need to do a ranking of myfulltext search in .order_by( ts_rank(sqlalchemy.sql.expression.func.to_tsvector('english', table.c.title )
.match(' machine & Verificated', postgresql_regconfig='english') )  )

Comment: You've also posted that as an answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/65373003/4799172 which it clearly isn't.

Comment: I did an edit but someone need to approve it first.

Comment: I didn't ask you to post the code in a comment; I asked you to re-post with it correctly formatted

Comment: @PredragDj be very careful with edits like this. I, personally, would be opening it with a view to decline. This is not based on you but the OP's original post and the fact that it can hide issues on their side

Comment: Ok, thank you for advice, I will keep it in mind.

Comment: thanks , its my first time using stack overflow